# Cairo Dock malfunction

Tags: settings, cairo-dock

I just upgraded recently to the new Ubuntu 14.04 and I downloaded and installed the **cairo dock** for my desktop.

The issue that I am having with it is not with the dock itself but with the windows for the advanced settings that keep going black when I try to open them. I can not see the options that I wish to change. I tried uninstalling it using

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then tried reinstalling it, but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Seems a bug. Which version are you using, and on top of what? Cairo-dock forums at http://glx-dock.org/bg_forumlist.php are in my experience very useful and responsive.